# Stop Redirect in SharePoint Designer Custom Action to initiate workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, custom-actions

I have a Document Library on SharePoint On premise.

I have created **SharePoint 2013 Workflow** for Document Library.

I have created **Custom Action** from SharePoint Designer to Initiate Workflow.

so my custom action is display in list item menu. when I have click on action workflow trigger.
But it will redirect to site Home page.
how to stop to redirect.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may have to use the "Navigate to URL" and type in the server relative url to the workflow initiation form while using tokens for the ID

```
/sites/example/_layouts/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List={ListId}&ID={ItemId}&TemplateID={<templateID of workflow}&Source=<url>
```

where `<url>` is wherever you want the user to navigate to after the initiation form has been pressed and `<template id of workflow>` is the template ID of the workflow you get by going to the initiation form manually and copying it from the URL.

Comment: Where do you get the template ID? I don't see this on the manual start page.